# Not joining full table

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I need to LEFT JOIN but the "right" table is very large and I only need values after 2018-01-01, while the whole table has records from up to 2012. To speed up my query I therefore need to not LEFT JOIN the full table, but the table with records > 2018-01-01. If I use a where statement at the end of my query it will still use the full table right? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put the where filter right in the join.

```
select * from tableA a
left Join tableB b on a.id=b.id and b.date > 2018-01-01
where a.field =''
```

Comment: Does the ON statement work the same as the where statement?

Comment: no it joins just the records that meet the criteria, you will want to make sure that there is an index on the date field. you can try both ways, and run a Data execution plan to see the difference.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I do not know what you mean by the index on the date field.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the constraint in the where clause will not behave the same as putting in the on clause.

The reason is that the outer join is performed first, followed by the where clause.  Any rows in the query that don't have a match in the optional table, the date column will be null.  Your where clause is applied next, and since null <> anything, you will drop all those rows. Basically, you'll turn your outer join into an inner join.  That's why you want to put any constraints on your optional table in the on clause, as shown in Dave Kelly's answer.

Comment: There's a nice Outer Join Case Study in the Teradata manuals: https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/SQL_Reference/B035-1146-160K/gea1472240815347.html#